# how to evaluate using tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I am using tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(...) to do distributed training, take the first worker as chief, and second worker to do evaluation. the cluster is as following with 8 workers and 2 ps.

```
{
    "cluster": {
        "ps": ["100.77.4.147:61415", "100.77.14.144:52383"],
        "chief": ["100.77.14.144:49606"],
        "worker": ["100.110.22.203:28312", "100.77.4.147:32299", "100.77.4.147:4950", "100.110.22.203:22196", "100.110.22.203:39327", "100.77.14.144:32888", "100.77.4.147:26919"]
    },
    "task": {
        "index": 0,
        "type": "evaluator"
    }
}
```

other regular worker set index from 0 to end

however, while run, errors happen:

```
// in the chief node has following errors
CreateSession failed because worker /job:worker/replica:0/task:1 returned error: Unavailable: OS Error
CreateSession failed because worker /job:worker/replica:0/task:2 returned error: Unavailable: OS Error
CreateSession failed because worker /job:worker/replica:0/task:3 returned error: Unavailable: OS Error
```

then I check other workers, found error as following

```
CreateSession still waiting for response from worker: /job:worker/replica:0/task:5
CreateSession still waiting for response from worker: /job:worker/replica:0/task:0
CreateSession still waiting for response from worker: /job:worker/replica:0/task:1
...
```

Did I set wrong cluster_spec? thanks

Answer (score 0):

update:

finally, it works. evaluator should not included in workers list.
FYI.